# При обновлении страницы данные повторно записываются в базу данных

Tags: php, form

Есть форма отправки комментария:

```html
<form method="POST" action="blog-single.php#leave_comment">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Name" name="name" class="form-control" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input placeholder="Email" name="email" class="form-control" type="email">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <textarea placeholder="Message" name="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <button type="submit" name="do_comment" class="btn btn-primary-lg center-block comment-form_submit fa_btn_grey">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Данные записываются в БД и все хорошо но при обновлении страницы данные опять записываются. Вот проверка на ошибки и запись в БД. Я пробовал решить эту проблему редиректом на эту же страницу(`header("Location: ...")`) но выбивало ошибку: `Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by`(путь к моему файлу, где код с хедером страницы, в начале файла я подключаю его `include`-ом). Подскажите, как можно решить эту проблему, желательно без переноса скрипта обработки в отдельный файл.

```
if( isset($_POST['do_comment']) ){
    $errors = array();

if( $_POST['name'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your name!';
}

if( $_POST['email'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your email!';
}

if( $_POST['message'] == '' ) {
    $errors[] = 'Enter your message!';
}

if ( empty($errors) ) {
    //No errors, comment can be added
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `comments` (`author`, `email`, `text`, `articles_id`) VALUES ('".$_POST['name']."', '".$_POST['email']."' , '".$_POST['message']."', '".$art_q['id']."') ");
}else {
    //Errors are present
    echo $errors['0'] . '<hr><br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Добрый вечер. unset($_POST); после записи в базу. А почему Вас так смущает обработчик в отдельном файле?

Comment: просто мне так удобнее) Сделал  `unset($_POST);` в условии `if ( empty($errors) )` но повторная запись не пропала

Comment: Делай редирект на ту же страницу после успешного добавления.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev я написал в вопросе что в чем у меня проблема с этим методом

Comment: @МаксимБуяков редирект у вас не получается сделать потому что вы не прочитали документацию к функции header. Эту функцию нельзя вызвать после того, как вы что нибудь выведите на страницу. Он должна быть вызвана, до вывода html кода.